# Create an evenly divided Sudoku board

Tags: css, html, dart

I've been trying to create a simple Sudoku board, but the problem is I am not that well in CSS, so, I can not get the Sudoku board to look normal. I've been trying to use Dart lang, and would like to keep using that.

Here is the sudoku.dart

```
void makeSudokuBoard(){


  for(var b = 0; b <3; b++){
    var tbody = board.createTBody();
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){

      TableRowElement rows = tbody.addRow();

      for(var j = 0; j < 9; j++){

        String puzzleplace = puzzle.substring(counter, counter+1);
        if(puzzleplace == "0"){ 

          rows.insertCell(j).text = "";
                rows.cells[j].setAttribute("contenteditable","true");


        }else{
        rows.insertCell(j).text = puzzleplace;
        rows.cells[j].setAttribute("contenteditable","false");
        }

        counter++;
      }

    }
    tbody.classes.add("tbody"+b.toString());
  }

  board.classes.add("board");
  document.querySelector('#container').append(board);
  document.querySelector(".board").appendHtml("<colgroup><col><col><col><colgroup><col><col><col><colgroup><col><col><col>");

}
```

Here is the css sheet I'm using.

```
table {

height: 70%;
    width: 40%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    table-layout: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;

}

colgroup, tbody{

    border: solid medium;
}



tr { border: solid thin; text-align: center;}
```

Here is how it always turns out however and I can't figure out how to fix it

[image: board]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create 3 tables. I think you should create one table with 9 rows and 9 columns and do the formatting entirely in CSS:

see http://jsfiddle.net/zoechi/45MzU/

```css
table {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    table-layout: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: calc(70vw / 9);
    height: calc(70vw / 9);
}

td:nth-child(3), td:nth-child(6), td:nth-child(9){
    border-right-width: 3px;
}

tr:nth-child(3) td, tr:nth-child(6) td, tr:nth-child(9) td{
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
}

tr:nth-child(1) td{
    border-top-width: 3px;
}

td:nth-child(1) {
    border-left-width: 3px;
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer to make the table size 70% (dynamic size).

Comment: This definitely worked, I had to remove the colgroups from the dart file to get the arrow keys to function and just remove creating tbodies in the for loops, but now it looks beautiful. I must learn css better